# Nginx how to add extra server configuration to without modifying nginx.conf

Tags: nginx, configuration

I want to add this extra config to my nginx.conf:

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:8081;
  rewrite     ^  https://$host$request_uri? redirect;
}
```

But as my app is deployed in a hosting service I don't want to modify the already present `nginx.conf`. It can be problematic.

Is there any way I can add this extra configuration without modifying nginx.conf?

Comment: Usually nginx's config includes every file from `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` and/or `/etc/nginx/conf.d`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no way you can add extra server configuration without modifying `nginx.conf` first. But good news is that you will have to modify nginx.conf only for once.

Just add this line in your `nginx.conf`

```
include /etc/nginx/config.d/*.conf;
```

You can name directory and path as per your choice.
create directory and save your extra configuration in that as `extra.conf` with `.conf` extension. Any files you save with `.conf`extension in this directory `/etc/nginx/config.d` will be automatically added to your nginx.conf.

You can even save multiple configurations like `extra1.conf` and `extra2.conf`
for different uses and you can delete one without affecting other.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way, but you need to insert some changes to nginx.conf

you can create a template file `extra_config` that contains

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:8081;
  rewrite     ^  https://$host$request_uri? redirect;
}
```

and in `nginx.conf` add this string

```
{% include '%path_to_template_file%/extra_config'}
```